# Compare a matrix against a column vector

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Arrays 'A' and vector 'B' below are part of pandas dataframe.

I have a large array `A` of form:

```
28  39  52
77  80  66
7   18  24
9   97  68
```

I have a vector `B` of form:

```
32
5
42
17
```

How do I compare pythonically each column of A against B. I am trying to get True/False values for A < B comparison to get the following result:

```
TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
```

I can do list comprehension syntax but is there a better way to pull this off. My array A and B are very large.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider the `pd.DataFrame` and `pd.Series`, `A` and `B`

```
A = pd.DataFrame([
        [28, 39, 52],
        [77, 80, 66],
        [7, 18, 24],
        [9, 97, 68]
    ])

B = pd.Series([32, 5, 42, 17])
```

## `pandas`

By default, when you compare a `pd.DataFrame` with a `pd.Series`, pandas aligns each index value from the series with the column names of the dataframe.  This is what happens when you use `A < B`.  In this case, you have 4 rows in your dataframe and 4 elements in your series, so I'm going to assume you want to align the index values of the series with the index values of the dataframe.  In order to specify the axis you want to align with, you need to use the comparison method rather than the operator.  That's because when you use the method, you can use the `axis` parameter and specify that you want `axis=0` rather than the default `axis=1`.

```
A.lt(B, axis=0)

       0      1      2
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2   True   True   True
3   True  False  False
```

I often just write this as `A.lt(B, 0)`

---

## `numpy`

In numpy, you also have to pay attention to the dimensionality of the arrays ***and*** you are assuming that the positions are already lined up.  The positions ***will*** be taken care of if they come from the same dataframe.

```
print(A.values)

[[28 39 52]
 [77 80 66]
 [ 7 18 24]
 [ 9 97 68]]

print(B.values)

[32  5 42 17]
```

Notice that `B` is a 1 dimensional array while A is a 2 dimensional array.  In order to compare `B` along the rows of `A` we need to reshape `B` into a 2 dimensional array.  The most obvious way to do this is with `reshape`

```
print(A.values < B.values.reshape(4, 1))

[[ True False False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True False False]]
```

However, these are ways in which you will commonly see others do the same reshaping

```
A.values < B.values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Or

```
A.values < B.values[:, None]
```

---

## timed back test

To get a handle of how fast these comparisons are, I've constructed the following back test.

```
def pd_cmp(df, s):
    return df.lt(s, 0)

def np_cmp_a2a(df, s):
    """To get an apples to apples comparison
    I return the same thing in both functions"""
    return pd.DataFrame(
        df.values < s.values[:, None],
        df.index, df.columns
    )

def np_cmp_a2o(df, s):
    """To get an apples to oranges comparison
    I return a numpy array"""
    return df.values < s.values[:, None]


results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([10, 1000, 100000], name='group size'),
    columns=pd.Index(['pd_cmp', 'np_cmp_a2a', 'np_cmp_a2o'], name='method'),
)

from timeit import timeit

for i in results.index:
    df = pd.concat([A] * i, ignore_index=True)
    s = pd.concat([B] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        results.set_value(
            i, j,
            timeit(
                '{}(df, s)'.format(j),
                'from __main__ import {}, df, s'.format(j),
                number=100
            )
        )

results.plot()
```

[image]

I can conclude that the `numpy` based solutions are faster but not all that much.  They all scale the same.

Comment: Since OP says the arrays are very large, performance comparison b/w Pandas vs Numpy would be much informative for future readers

Comment: I really like your pandas "timeit" wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

The more efficient is to go down numpy level (A,B are DataFrames here):

```
A.values<B.values
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html#pandas.DataFrame.lt) and calling `squeeze` on `B` so it flattens the df to a 1-D Series:

```
In [107]:
A.lt(B.squeeze(),axis=0)

Out[107]:
       0      1      2
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2   True   True   True
3   True  False  False
```

The problem is that without `squeeze` then it will try to align on the column labels which we don't want. We want to broadcast the comparison along the column-axis

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option using numpy is with [`numpy.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis)

```
In [99]: B = B[:, np.newaxis]

In [100]: B
Out[100]: 
array([[32],
       [ 5],
       [42],
       [17]])

In [101]: A < B
Out[101]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Essentially, we're converting the vector `B` into a 2D array so that numpy can broadcast when comparing two arrays of different shapes.

Comment: @EdChum `np.newaxis` is synonymous with `None`.  `np.newaxis is None` evaluates to `True`

Comment: @piRSquared ah.. I didn't know that, I've always use `None` in these situations

Comment: @EdChum as do most people because it's 6 characters less to write :-)

Comment: @piRSquared yeah, I'm lzy 2

Comment: @EdChum I prefer this way since it's more intuitive (implies that we're increasing the array axis by 1, each time we use `newaxis`) and readable :)