# How to get One-Hot encoded matrix from a survey table and vector of answers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a surveys' answers from the participants in a pandas dataframe:

```
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A' ...],
 ['D', 'B', 'B', 'A' ...],
 ......................

 ['D', 'C', 'C', 'A' ...]]
```

and I have a vector of keys to the survey:

`['D', 'B', 'B', 'A' ...]`

I need to get a dataframe which displays the boolean results of survey like:

```
 [0, 1, 0, 1 ...],
 [1, 1, 1, 1 ...],
 ......................

 [1, 0, 0, 1 ...]]
```

I've tried to use pd.get_dummies(users_answ, keys) but that seems wrong

Comment: It is unclear from your question and data sample how your data is structured in terms of if answers are by user or by question.  Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: @itprorh66 already found, thanks anyway
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790968/compare-a-matrix-against-a-column-vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way seems to use pandas eq function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html#pandas.DataFrame.eq

So the whole solution oneline:

```
users_answ.eq(keys, axis=0)
```

Alternative solution:

```
#new array
checked_answ = []
#taking each row of surveys answers df
for r in range(0, users_answ.shape[0]): 
    row = users_answ.iloc[r].tolist()
    #creating the array for this row
    p = []
    for i in range(0, len(keys)):
        if(keys[i] == row[i]):
            p.append(1)
        else:
            p.append(0)
    checked_answ.append(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply check the equality between the DataFrame and the list. The list should get aligned to the `DataFrame` across the columns:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[*'ABCA'],[*'DBBA'],[*'DCCA']])
keys = [*'DBBA']

print(df)
   0  1  2  3
0  A  B  C  A
1  D  B  B  A
2  D  C  C  A

print(keys)
['D', 'B', 'B', 'A']

print(df == keys)
       0      1      2     3
0  False   True  False  True
1   True   True   True  True
2   True  False  False  True

# If you want actual integers instead of booleans
print((df == keys).astype(int))
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  0  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  0  0  1
```